# T-SQL deny column update even from stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've got a question regarding ms sql permissions

I set DENY permission for column UPDATE

```
DENY UPDATE ON [MyTable] (MyColumn) TO [PrincipalName] ;
```

It work fine (prevents MyColumn to be updated when I directly UPDATE MyTable's MyColumn), but it still grants user to update this column via stored procedure.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Deny the user access to the stored procedure as well. (See [Ownership Chains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676(v=sql.105).aspx) for explanation as to why this happens)

Comment: But I don't want to DENY stored procedure execution because it updates other columns and this is legal. I just want to prevent some users (by application role) to update some column (not all columns)

Comment: Even if there was no such thing as ownership chaining and the permissions were checked this still wouldn't work it would throw an `UPDATE permission was denied` error. You need a separate procedure.

Comment: It's a pity that T-SQL doesn't have a very simple thing: prevent column updating in any way (direct table update or from sp).

Comment: That's not how it works. If you have execute permission on the stored proc then you can do what ever the stored proc does because that way you CAN deny UPDATE on anything you like and the stored proc acts as guardian on the data as it is the only way to update it. If you don't want the user to be able to use the stored proc, don't give them access. If you want certain users to not do certain things in the stored proc then you are going to have to write the logic yourself to do that.

Comment: As Colin and Martin said, if you need this functionality, you will either have to write a new stored proc for these users or add conditional logic to your existing stored proc.

Comment: Thanks you to all, but neither solution you offered is right for me. Maybe it's my blame that I do not explained the problem clearly. 
Once again (this time clearer) : I have a stored procedure to update some table. By default all the application users have rights to update every column of this table. But I have universal permission system assigning application roles to the desired users. That is, administrator can create application roles DENY-ing for update some columns of any tables. Meaning that users can change data in some specific columns (these columns list is not predefined).

Comment: ... Continued. But if they [users] trying to change prohibited columns (by administrator) error should raise.

Comment: Give the procedure that updates the table a different owner than the table if you don't want ownership chaining and you want permissions to be checked directly then.

Comment: I also tried 
CREATE PROC ...
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER/OWNER
but still without success

Comment: Ummm... what about sp_changeobjectowner to break ownership chain?

Answer (score 0):

Colin Mackay is right. Stored procedure encapsulates business logic and permissions.

You can use something like

```
IF user_name()='PrincipalName' raiserror(N'Update denied',15,0)
```

to check user in the stored procedure. Or You can create an update trigger for then table